# Focus window after changing workspace

Tags: google-chrome, xmonad

After i switch workspaces in xmonad with e.g. Alt+3 no window in workspace 3 has focus.

I'd like xmonad to automatically give focus to the top window in the workspace i'm switching to.

Update: this seems to be a google-chrome issue

[1] https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1309801

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to apply the ewmh combinator

```
import XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops 

main = xmonad $ ewmh defaults
```